# Create new Git repository from within VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

An existing project is synched with a Git repository. Within Visual Studio Code, is it possible to publish the project to a new repository and switch to using that?

None of the Git commands from the View -> Command Palette appear appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: There is an option to [add a remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laa8R.png) to which it will then ask to pick a remote source (typically GitHub).  Is that what you are looking for??  Unless you mean 100% from scratch - then I think you can initialize a new local repository, and push to a new remote afterwards, but I think the remote needs to exist in GitHub first.